# LEFT JOIN USING 5 TABLE VALUE Sum And Minus

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to Sum and minus operation in  5 tables using left joins but quantity added automatic increment in that function

```
SELECT item.*, 
       SUM(IFNULL(item.item_quantity, 0) 
           + IFNULL(inward.passedquantity, 0) 
           + IFNULL(op.opening_stock, 0) - IFNULL(bom.quantitytopick, 0) + 
           IFNULL(adj.adjustment_quantity, 0)) AS totalquality 
FROM   itemmaster item 
       LEFT JOIN inwardmaster inward 
              ON item.item_barcode = inward.item_barcode 
       LEFT JOIN openingstock op 
              ON item.item_barcode = op.item_barcode 
       LEFT JOIN bomupload bom 
              ON item.item_barcode = bom.item_barcode 
       LEFT JOIN adjustment_inventory adj 
              ON item.item_barcode = adj.item_barcode 
GROUP  BY item.item_barcode
```

Comment: these queries to make stock report

Comment: Please provide more details and explanation of what you want to achieve and what problem you are facing.

Comment: i want any table data entry added and display itemmaster table but this query is dispaly correctly but quantity is not correct

Comment: Do you want data from one table or all five?

Comment: i want all table merge in one  table using select query